# what does 'objects being subclassable' mean?

Tags: python

[Dive into Python](http://diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/everything_is_an_object.html) -

> Different programming languages define “object” in different ways. In some, it means that all objects must have attributes and methods; in others, it means that all objects are subclassable. In Python, the definition is looser; some objects have neither attributes nor methods (more on this in Chapter 3), and not all objects are subclassable (more on this in Chapter 5).

I am coming from `C++/Java` background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be subclassable means that you can inherit from them. e.g.

```
class Foo(object):
    pass
```

`object` here is subclassable because Foo can inherit from it.

Answer (score -1):

In this context I think it is talking about Inheritance or Interfaces. As in, you can subclass a Human into Male and Female.